# Save Radio button value "int" in to shared preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, radio-button, sharedpreferences, radio-group

I am still having problem with this radio buttons :(. I am still trying to create a setting page which allow user to select their text colour and once they have selected from this setting activity and all other activities with listen to the sharedpreferences change as well.

I know how to save text and get text from a shared preferences between activities but int ?  As I need the radio checked value and this method will be passed on to other activities to set those textview colours.

can anyone check the code for me please?

and I am very new to android and general programming.

```
public class Text_Colour extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5;
    TextView tv1, tv2;
    RadioGroup rg1;
    Button bt1;
    String red, yellow, green, blue;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile"; 


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.colours);

        loadPreferences();

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        rb5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(Colour_change_b);

        //tv1.setOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    View.OnClickListener Colour_change_b = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == bt1) {

             if (rb1.isChecked()== true) {
                 tv2.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                } 
                if (rb2.isChecked() == true) {
                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

                } 
                if (rb3.isChecked() == true) {
                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

                } 
                if (rb4.isChecked() == true) {
                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                } 
                if (rb5.isChecked() == true) {
                    rb5.getId();
                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                } 
                else { 
                }
                SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings1.edit();
                editor.putInt("colour", rb1.getId());
                editor.commit();
                finish();   
    }
    }
    };
    private void loadPreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        tv1.setTextColor(settings.getId("colour", ""));
        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(Text_Colour.this);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {

        loadPreferences();
    }   
    }
```

Much appreciated for your time guys.

Comment: what do you expect `editor.putInt("colour", rb1.getId());` to do ?

Comment: ermmmmm im quite new to this but my logic tells me that get the int then put it in to "colour" and not so sure why Ive got rb1.getId() there... if I use rb1.getText().toString() the editor.putInt will become cannot be resolved.

Comment: rb1 is the first radio button. it contains nothing about the other ones, therefore cannot help you in knowing which item is selected.

Comment: you are right, it should be radigroups. Thanks I will looking to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your `RadioGroup`. You can use `setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener listener)` to receive instantly the value of the new color, and you can use `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` to get the checked  radioButtonId.

However, there is a catch. The *Id* is generated at compile time by android. It is not guaranteed to remain consistent between compilations. Use `indexOfChild(View child)` if you want to get the index of the RadioButton in the RadioGroup.

To get the value, you need a `getInt()`, then a `getChildAt(int index)`, then a `getId()` and a `check(int id)`.

Comment: +1 for the `indexOfChild(View child)`. Might be even better with an example of the usage of *"`getInt()`, then a `getChildAt(int index)`, then a `getId()`*"!